# como puedo abrir un Modal a partir de una selección de un servicio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal, webforms

Estoy haciendo un `webforms` de un `ecommerce` y quiero que cuando el cliente seleccione: *Comprar un Producto*, se abra un modal y pregunte si seguir comprando o ir a pedidos.... cuando presiono el botón no sucede nada. Los servicios los carga perfectamente y vienen desde una BD.

Aquí les pego el codigo del `MenuPrincipal.aspx`

En este primer content agrego los archivos de `Boostrap` para dar formato.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="../../Script/Thirdparty/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Script/Thirdparty/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

** comienza el segundo content**
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <br />
    <br />
   <div  style="background-image:url('../../Content/Image/banner-curso-degrade.png')">
   <br />
   <br />     
   <h2  style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:30px">Nuestros Servicios</h2>
   <br />     
   <br />
   </div>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Shared/PaginaMaestraCliente.Master" %>




   **----------------------------- carga de menú de servicios -------------------------------------**
<div class="tab-pane active" id="panel-810103">
  <div class="row">
    <asp:Repeater ID="InfoServicio" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
         <HeaderTemplate>
          
          </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div  class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail" style="text-align: center;">
              <%--  <li>--%>
                   <div >
                       <br />
                       <br />
                       <br />
                        <div class="caption">                      
                        <h2><%# Eval("Titulo")%></h2>
                        <a runat="server" href='<%#Eval("IdServicio")%>'><img src='/Content/Image/<%# Eval("URLImagen")%>' class="img-responsive col-md-12"/></a>
                        <h3><%# Eval("Descripcion")%></h3>
                        <strong><p>$<span><%# Eval("Precio")%></span></strong></p>
                        </div>
                         <div class="item-toolbar">
       
                             <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " data-target ="#mdl_servicio_agregado" data-toggle="modal"  comprar</a>"
                                             
                         
                         </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
         
            </FooterTemplate>
             
    </asp:Repeater>
  </div>
</div>
     
        **----------------- fin de carga de menu de servicios ---------------------------**

        **--------------------------- display del MODAL carrito de compra ---------------------------**

     <div class="modal fade" id="mdl_servicio_agregado">    
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header text-center"> <%--encabezado de la ventana--%>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title" style="color: #29ab29;">"Felicitaciones"</h3>
                    </div> <%--fin del encabezado de la ventana --%>
                    <div class="modal-body text-center"> <%--Cuerpo de la ventana--%>

                     
                    <h4 style="color: black;"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="ElServicio"></asp:Label> <span id="servicio"></span><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="ServicioCorrectamenteAgregadoAlCarrito"></asp:Label></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="text-center">
           
                            <button type="button" id="btn-pedidos" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 200px;"><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="IrAPedidos"></asp:Label></button>
          
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="SeguirComprando" class="btn" style="width: 200px; background-color: black; color: #fff;" data-dismiss="modal" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
    </div>
         **-------------- Fin del Modal del carrito de compra -------**
</asp:Content>
```

La idea es que cuando el cliente elija un servicio se abra el modal y le dé la opción de seguir comprando y permanecer en la página o ir a *Pedidos* para continuar con el proceso de la compra y pagos.

Comment: Cambia el orden de los scripts, en  la parte superior debe ir jQuery y debajo de este el bootstrap.js, en el head

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: mencionas que al presionar el boton "no sucede nada", pero cual boton es el que presionas? es el Button1? o btn-pedidos? porque veo dos implementados de forma diferentes, uno es un boton html y el otro un boton de asp.net

Comment: el modal es el de boostrap ? si tienes que redireccionar deberias realziarlo usando javascript no eventos de controles de asp.net

Comment: @JheymanMejia gracias por tu respuesta...era esa la solucion al problema... gracias